# Distance Matrix of two datasets

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, distance, address

I have two datasets of the same addresses, one geocoded with Google, the other with Nominatim.

Now I want to compare address1 of dataset1 with address1 of dataset2, then address2 of dataset2 with address2 of dataset2 and so on.

Using QGIS, I tried the `distance matrix` and the `Distance to nearest hub`-modules. The problem is, that they only give out the nearest point and not the appropriate point/address.

So far, I didn't try ArcGIS, but am not aware of an easy solution there anyway.

Is there a way to write a python script for my issue or a module I am not aware of?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I now created an ID column in both datasets, then created a distance matrix (with Processing > QGIS > Vector analysis tools > Distance matrix) and selected the needed columns in the attribute table with the expression "'InputID'='OutputID'". Then I extracted them with right click on the dataset and "Save as". That method worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS you can try the `Distance Matrix` of Saga (under Processing > Tools > Saga > Shapes - Points). This calculates a distance matrix for all points in one layer only, but does include an ID. Just combine the two layers into one (e.g. with Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge Shapefile to One). Make sure that you have some attribute that makes it possible to separate the two layers within the results.

Answer (score 0):

Arcgis solution, but applicable to any decent GIS.

Project your layers.
Calculate xy columns
Join table to another by address.
Calculate distance between 2 pairs of coordinates