# Counting points within certain distance of each other in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, distance, count

I have a shapefile right now that contains many points. I would like to count the number of point points that are within 150 ft of each other.

[image]

For example, I should count 8 locations with points within 150 ft of each other.

I tried making buffers around the points (see below) but each buffer isn't an individual.

[image]

Comment: Distance Matrix? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/194162/276

Comment: I tried but I dont think I understand how to do this. This distance matrix created a matrix of all the points and the distance to the next nearest point. What I want is to essentially combine all the points within 150 ft of each other and then count how many of those exist.

Comment: To get all buffers individually use the "Multipart to singleparts" and then apply the "Count points in polygon".

Answer (score 8):

Open the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) and use this expression:

```
aggregate(
    'Point_layer', -- replace with the name/id of your point layer
    'count',
    $id,
    filter:=distance(
        $geometry,
        geometry(@parent)
        ) <= 45.72 -- set here the distance in the projection units
    ) - 1
```

replace `Point_layer` with the name or id of your point layer.

Answer (score 3):

Try also the ["DBSCAN clustering"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#dbscan-clustering) geoalgorithm. It contains a setting called *'Maximum distance between clustered points'* and will provide in the end the `"CLUSTER_SIZE"` attribute.