# Counting number of points in one layer within fixed distance to points in another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, expression, proximity, count

In QGIS 3.22.7 I want to count the number of points on point *'layer B'* within 60m of each point on point *'layer A'* and add a column to the data on point *'layer A'*. What is wrong with the following equation?

I couldn't get it to work by rewriting A into B. All the elements are zero.
Or can I do it with the processing tool's functionality?

```
aggregate(
    'A', 
    'count',
    $id,
    filter:=distance(
        $geometry,
        geometry('B' )
        ) <= 60
    )
```

I am referring to this post: [Counting points within certain distance of each other in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434388/counting-points-within-certain-distance-of-each-other-in-qgis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this expression on layer A:

```
array_length(
    overlay_nearest (
        'B',
        $id,
        limit:=-1,
        max_distance:=60
    )
)
```

*Blue points: layer B; red point: Layer A, labeled with the number of blue points within 60 meters, calculated with the expression above:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked well.

Comment: When I want to apply a filter to layer B, can I calculate it using only the field calculator?
Do I need to output the filtered data once?

Comment: According to the policy of this site, you should add another post as this is a new question

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You must perform the calculation on layer **A**.

There are some problems with your expression:

1. The [`aggregate`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate) function allows to do some kind of a loop in the features of a layer, so you need to loop throw the objects of layer **B** filtering by distance. Some times this can looks confusing, because the field calculator is performing a loop and if you are using aggregates this will perform loops for every calculated feature.
2. When you use the filter in the [`aggregate`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate) function you can use the @parent variable to refer to the current object that's being calculated.

The correct expression is:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='B', -- here you loop throw the features of layer B
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:=$id,
    filter:=distance( -- this filter will be used to filter features of layer B
        $geometry, -- here $geometry refers to the geometry of layer B
        geometry(@parent) -- @parent is a variable containing the current feature that's being calculated of layer A
        ) <= 60
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!When I want to apply a filter to layer B, can I calculate it using only the field calculator?
Do I need to output the filtered data once?

Comment: @osakanatengoku, With "apply a filter to layer B", you mean filter features of layer **B** that are between a fixed distance from a feature of layer **A**?